# XPath when a root node and element have different Name Space attributes

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I got struck with a problem in VB.Net getting Xpath for an XML element as shown below:

```
<Parent xmlns:"http://www.sample.com">    
   <body>      
       <Child xmlns:"http://www.notsample.com">

           <element type="xyz"> ghghghghghg </element> 

       </Child>    
   </body>
</Parent>
```

I need Xpath of the "element" in above XML using VB.Net NameSpace Manager

For the "body" node i have done and its working but i couldnt do the same to "element":

```
dim bodynode as XMLNode=XML.SelectSingleNode(//ns:body,nsmngr)
```

where "nsmngr" is the namespacemanger created by me and "ns" is the name space of the "parent node" (which the "body" node inherits) added to the namespace manager as "ns"

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two different solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

**There are two different ways to construct the needed XPath expression**:

1. **Define a second namespace binding** with `NamespaceManager`, say `ns2:` bound to `http://www.notsample.com`. Then use:

`/*/ns:body/ns2:Child/ns2:element`

2. **Don't use namespaces at all**:

`/*/*[name()='body']/*[name()='Child']/*[name()='element']`

Answer (score 0):

Given the following xml:

```
<OuterElem  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1" xmlns:test1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1">
<test:parent>
    <test1:child1>blabla1</test1:child1>
    <test1:child2>blabla2</test1:child2>
    <test:child2>blabla3</test:child2>
</test:parent>
<test1:child1>blabla4</test1:child1>
</OuterElem>
```

the following xslt (xslt 1.0) copies all nodes except **"test:parent/test1:child1"**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:test="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1" xmlns:test1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test:parent/test1:child1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will be:

```
<OuterElem xmlns:test="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1" xmlns:test1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <test:parent>
        <test1:child2>blabla2</test1:child2>
        <test:child2>blabla3</test:child2>
    </test:parent>
    <test1:child1>blabla4</test1:child1>
</OuterElem>
```

Comment: This is not an XSLT question, therefore your answer is not what is wanted.

Comment: @ dimitre: If you look at the examples you will see the 2 namespace bindings and the way to specify the xpath to a node belonging to 2 different namespaces: "test:parent/test1:child1" - so I would say it does answer the question